# Set a checkbox in a ng-repeat to checked by default

Tags: angularjs

I have the below checkbox that is in a ng-repeat where this should always be checked by default. The issue that I am running into is that I can set it to checked at the controller scope but not at the item (perf) scope. So if I set it at the controller scope, if you unchecked it, all of the items (perfs) unchecked. BTW, from all of the examples that I have come across show the checkbox being initially checked based on a value in the item array which I don't have.

```
<div ng-repeat="(perf) in $ctrl.filteredPerfs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pull-right cs-fg" ng-class="{'hidden': perf.showContigSeats == 'N'}">
      <md-input-container class="cs_ic">
        <span>
            <md-checkbox md-block class="ada-reserve" ng-model="perf.resTkts"></md-checkbox>
        </span>
        <span class="cs-ada-label">Only reserve tickets next to each other</span>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but then you can't uncheck it. I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1

Initialize `perf.resTkts` as true:

```
<md-checkbox md-block ng-model="perf.resTkts" ng-init="perf.resTkts = true"></md-checkbox>
```

## Solution 2

Use [`ng-checked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked):

```
<md-checkbox md-block ng-model="perf.resTkts" ng-checked="true"></md-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ng-checked : If this expression evaluates as truthy, the 'md-checked' css class is added to the checkbox and it will appear checked

```
<md-checkbox md-block class="ada-reserve" ng-checked="perf.resTkts" ng-model="perf.resTkts"></md-checkbox>
```

> set perf.resTkts = true for default

```
 <md-checkbox md-block class="ada-reserve" ng-checked="true" ng-model="perf.resTkts"></md-checkbox>
```